# Injecting service into component not working

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am newbie to angular2, and i am working on a simple application where i want to call a **Service Method** `GetAuthors()` in a component, but somehow my service **Method** `GetAuthors()` is not calling. I have also use `@Injectable()` in my service. Everything works fine in component and shows up the result in browser but not the `service` part, i don't know what's the issue and What i am missing, Help me out.

Here is my code

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthorComponent} from './author.component';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: '<h1>Hello Angular!</h1><authors></authors>',
 directives:[AuthorComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**author.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {AuthorService} from './author.service'

@Component({
 selector:"authors",
 template:`
 <h2>Author</h2>
 <p>{{ title }}</p>
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="#author of authors">{{ author }}</li>
 </ul>
 `,
 })

export class AuthorComponent {
  title = 'This is title for Author Component';
  authors;
  constructor(authorServie : AuthorService){
    this.authors = authorServie.GetAuthors();
  }
}
```

Here is my service
**author.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthorService {
  GetAuthors() : string[] {
   return ["Author 1", "Author 2", "Author 3"];
  }    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my service Method is not calling". Do you get an error message?

Comment: Unrelated, but it's a good practice to call the service in ngOnInit rather than the constructor.

Comment: i am not getting any error that's the problem, but the array in my `author.service` does not shows up in the broswer

Comment: Isn't the syntax of ngFor `let author of authors`?

Comment: @JBNizet i will search for `ngOnInit`, thanks. but why isn't in the service not giving me any result. ? if i assign the `authors` an `array` directly and loop through it then its working, but not in the service.

Comment: Is your your service provided?

Comment: @muetzerich what you mean by that? i have `imported` the service in the `component`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your service in your component, you have to mark the service as **injectable** and add it into the component providers.

From the Angular documentation:

> @Injectable() marks a class as available to an injector for
>   instantiation. Generally speaking, an injector will report an error
>   when trying to instantiate a class that is not marked as
>   @Injectable().

I reccomend you to checkout this article about Angular`s [Dependency injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html).

**author.service.ts**

```
@Injectable() // <- Mark your service as injectable
export class AuthorService {
   GetAuthors() : string[] {
      return ["Author 1", "Author 2", "Author 3"];
   }    
}
```

**author.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {AuthorService} from './author.service'

@Component({
 selector:"authors",
 providers: [ AuthorService ], // <- Add your services here
 template:`
    <h2>Author</h2>
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <ul>
       <li *ngFor="#author of authors">{{ author }}</li>
    </ul>
 `,
 })

export class AuthorComponent {
  title = 'This is title for Author Component';
  authors;
  constructor(authorServie : AuthorService){
    this.authors = authorServie.GetAuthors();
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any other problem with it.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Try to **provide your service** in your component.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {AuthorService} from './author.service'

@Component({
 selector:"authors",
 providers: [AuthorService],
 template:`
 <h2>Author</h2>
 <p>{{ title }}</p>
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="#author of authors">{{ author }}</li>
 </ul>
 `,
 })

export class AuthorComponent {
  title = 'This is title for Author Component';
  authors;
  constructor(authorServie : AuthorService){
    this.authors = authorServie.GetAuthors();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but we have to add the **@Injectable()** decorator in our service. Otherwise the dependency injection system will not know about the service.